# Simplification of Enum and its associated values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of values which i am maintaining like this,

```
        public enum DisplayUnits
    {
        Vertical = 0,
        Horizontal = 1,
        Track = 2,
        Empty = 3,

    }
    public static string DisplayUnitsImage(DisplayUnits unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case DisplayUnits.Vertical:
                return @"/image1";
            case DisplayUnits.Horizontal:
                return @"/image2";
            case DisplayUnits.Track:
                return @"/image3";
            case DisplayUnits.Empty:
                return @"/image4";
            default:
                return @"/image5";
        }

    }
    public static string DisplayUnitID(DisplayUnits unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case DisplayUnits.Vertical:
                return @"1234";
            case DisplayUnits.Horizontal:
                return @"1235";
            case DisplayUnits.Track:
                return @"1236";
            case DisplayUnits.Empty:
                return @"1237";
            default:
                return @"1238";
        }
    }
```

For retrieving the image path i ll call the method by passing the enum.
Can it be written in simpler manner because for adding one value i need to change in three places?
Using of Tuple is recommended in this context?

Comment: No.  Keep it close together, add a comment to the enum as a reminder, favor an exception over a default.

Comment: Ok. That exception part is really helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me change my answer completely.

As soon as you state, that you need to hardcode all possible `unitid`s and `image`s, you may have them stored into an array in your code like:

```
static string[] Images = 
{ 
    "/VerticalImage", 
    "/HorizontalImage", 
    "/TrackImage", 
    "/EmptyImage" 
}; //and so on...
```

that is the proper image (or unitid) is stored at the position matching relevant `DisplayUnits` `int` representation.

Then you'll be able to have the desired method work like this:

```
public static string DisplayUnitsImage(DisplayUnits unit)
{
    return string.Concat(Images[(int)unit], (int)unit);
}
```

So the only things you'll need to edit, if the `DisplayUnits` enum is edited, are

1. change the enum itself
2. change each of the arrays containing data (`string[] Images` in this example)

You needn't to edit the bodies of the methods (`DisplayUnitsImage`, `DisplayUnitID`, and others if any).

Or even easier. If all your methods work similarly, that is simply concat the data field and unit representation, then you may have one method instead all of them:

```
public static string DisplayUnitsData(string[] data, DisplayUnits unit)
{
    return string.Concat(data[(int)unit], (int)unit);
}
```

and pass the appropriate array (like `Images` in this example) as `data` argument:

```
string result = DisplayUnitsData(Images, DisplayUnits.Vertical);
```

Comment: as i stated in other comment, i image and id may change, not serial number. in that case what will be ur decision?

Comment: @Olivarsham I cannot understand, what you mean. Could you, please, explain it in greater detail?

Comment: The image name will not be like 'image'. it may vary.

Comment: @Olivarsham either pass the proper value as another method parameter, for example `string DisplayUnitID(DisplayUnits unit, string id){ return string.Format("{1}{0}", (int)unit + 4,id);}` or I completely misunderstand you: that is, if there should be **different** `unitid` and `image` **for each enum member**, shouldn't you hardcode **each of them** (if they cannot be generated or retrieved from some source instead)?

Comment: Yeah, need to hardcode it. But i wanted to give Enum and path in same place. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: @Olivarsham I've edited my answer. I hope now it's closer to what you're really trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String DisplayUnitsImage(Int32 value)
{
    return @"/image" + value;
}

public static String DisplayUnitID(Int32 value)
{
    return "123" + value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks . but my image name may vary. in that case what to do?